# How to upload image exact specified dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using this code I am trying to upload ONLY images with size of `512X512` and unset the file input when any other sizes selected but I am always getting `not a valid size of 512X512` even though selecting correct image size of `512X512`

I am working on the below code, and am looking how to fix it. Basically what I want is unset/unlink/unload an image which is not exact size of `512X512` and empty the file input

```js
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$("#file").change(function(e) {
  var file, img;
  if ((file = this.files[0])) {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      //alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
    };
    img.onerror = function() {
      alert("not a valid file: " + file.type);
    };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);

 // if (this.width != 512 && this.height != 512) {
 
    if (this.width != 512 || this.height != 512) {
      $("#file").val('');
      alert("not a valid size of 512X512");
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" />
```

Comment: move the `if (this.width...` into the `img.onload` part, `this` where your calling it is not the image but instead `$("#file")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move this section:

```
if (this.width != 512 || this.height != 512) {
  $("#file").val('');
  alert("not a valid size of 512X512");
}
```

into the `image.onload` function block.

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/4N6D9/1/